# How can I call for an info to be shown in JTextField()

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

here are two classes I want to get "Port" shown in JTextField, thanks

Class 1

```
System.out.println("using port "+portId.getName());
```

Class 2

```
textField = new JTextField();
frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "5, 3, left, default");
textField.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: Add a textfield update method to class 2

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your class 2 and call it from class 1.

```
public void updatePort(final String port) {
    // SwingUtilities.invokeLater is only needed if the method is called from outside the EDT
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            textField.setText(port);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get "Port" shown in JTextField

It is little confusing whether you want the port to be shown in `JTextField` or you want to get the port which is shown in `JTextField`. I am providing here the way to achieve both task.
Add a method in `class 2` as follows:

```
pubic String getPort()//to get port shown in JTextField
{
  return textField.getText();
}
public void setPort(String port)//to show the port in JTextField
{
   textField.setText(port);
}
```

And within `class 1` you can write as follows:

```
Class2 obj = new Class2();
String port = obj.getPort();//to get Port from JTextField
obj.setPort(port);//to set port in JTextField
```